# Laravel 11 PHPUnit tests Passport install

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-11

Before doing tests, I am doing migrations from scratch, and I am using normal MySQL for that; here is the coding I am using to run migrations.

```
public function manageDatabase(): void
{
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
    Artisan::call('migrate:fresh --seed');
    Artisan::call('passport:install');
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
}
```

The problem is that `Artisan::call('passport:install');` is not running (I got it from the stack trace), and the error is where I am only asserting true is true.

> 1. Tests\Unit\ExampleTest::test_that_true_is_true ErrorException:
>    stream_isatty(): 1 bytes of buffered data lost during stream
>    conversion!

Stack trace:

```
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php:256
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Concerns\ConfiguresPrompts.php:30
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:178
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Concerns\CallsCommands.php:67
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Concerns\CallsCommands.php:28
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\passport\src\Console\InstallCommand.php:43
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:41
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:93
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:35
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:662
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:212
{PATH}\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:279
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php:181
{PATH}\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:1031
{PATH}\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:318
{PATH}\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:169
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php:162
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php:423
{PATH}\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:357
{PATH}\tests\TestDatabaseTrait.php:19
{PATH}\tests\Unit\ExampleTest.php:15
```

WHERE `TestDatabaseTrait.php:19` is `Artisan::call('passport:install');`

And indeed, the `oauth_clients` table is empty. How can we fix that?

Comment: Why are you running those commands? you do not have to do that, first, you have to use `use RefreshDatabase;` or `use DatabaseTransaction;` trait, you do not need to clear the config cache, it should never be cached at all (in local environments, specially when running tests), do not install passport (or anything) when running tests, the stuff should already be installed, can you clear all these doubts? why are you doing all those steps before a test?

Comment: I need to login and do xhrs during tests that is why i need passport installed. And I don’t think the client keys will work without cache clearing. And for the tests to be valid I want a fresh migration. I don’t know a lot about RefreshDatabase can you help with that

Comment: Related to the database, you have a dedicated section on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test), check it out so you understand how to use that. I did not understand what you mean with "I need to login and do xhrs", what is xhrs? isn't [this](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/http-tests) helpful? Please, explain more (how you are testing) so we can fully help you